# Python: Import csv with format bytes using pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas, byte

I have got a csv where each entry looks like this:

```
b'A\xd3.\x80\xc7\x83\x98\xd3}\xd7g\xcc+\xb5T\xde'
```

I want to import the csv and while importing python should convert the string from the csv to a byte. So I would end up with something like this:

```
temp
b'A\xd3.\x80\xc7\x83\x98\xd3}\xd7g\xcc+\xb5T\xde'
type(temp)
<class 'bytes'>
```

I am using pandas for the import `df=pd.read_csv('Filename')` and pandas saves each entry as `object`, however when I access each element it converts it to a string

```
temp= df.iloc[0,0]
temp
"b'A\\xd3.\\x80\\xc7\\x83\\x98\\xd3}\\xd7g\\xcc+\\xb5T\\xde'"
type(temp)
<class 'str'>
```

but I would like that it uses the bytes format which does not have the `\\` , is there an elegent way to solve this besides manipulating the string and converting to bytes manually. If pandas is the wrong way I am happy to use a different one.
Thanks